# Swap frontpage based on season in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a client that has a tourism site (wordpress). They want to have a different homepage featured depending on if it is winter or summer. I would ideally like to control this by date automatically by creating 2 pages. Is there a way to specify the frontpage in wp-config based on JS or php date? They will need to have the option of swapping to the alternate season page if they are planning ahead. Not worried about other pages, just setting the frontpage to default based on date. ie. Nov 1 Summer changes to winter homepage. May 1 winter page changes to summer.

Comment: Why couldn't you just create two or more pages and then go into Settings > Reading and set whichever one you want to be the front page whenever you feel like changing it out?

Comment: WordPress 4.9 is due to release in 2-3 weeks. In that release there is bundled capability to schedule changesets in the customizer. You should be able to use that functionality to swap pages based on date so long as the date of the switch will happen after Nov 14th (expected date of 4.9 release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the two pages you want on Wordpress Pages... Let's call them

`Page Winter` (pageid = 1) and `Page Summer` (pageid = 2)

Then create a new Page Template in your child them and add this on it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Seasons Page
 */
 ?>

$currentMonth = date("n");

if ( $currentMonth > 11 && $currentMonth < 3 ) {
//Winter
   $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=1"); while($recent->have_posts()) : 
      $recent->the_post();
      echo '<h3>' . the_title() . '</h3>';
      the_content(); 
   endwhile;

} else {
//Sprint - Summer - Autumn
   $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); while($recent->have_posts()) : 
      $recent->the_post();
      echo '<h3>' . the_title() . '</h3>';
      the_content(); 
   endwhile;
}
```

Then create a new Wordpress page called "Home page" and choose the template you just created. Set this page as your real home page.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason the_title needs to be called in addition to the_content ? I'm worried how it might affect SEO?

Comment: It's not necessary. I just added it there so you can see the difference on the two pages. You can skip it.